# Total Pressure - uses in calculations and simulations

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, simulations

I believe that I understand the definition of *static pressure* and *total pressure* and how to measure them. 
However, it seems as if I do not yet fully understand how/when to use each one.

I'm currently reading a paper about simulating compressible internal flow, where the authors specify the entry/initial conditions as total pressure and total temperature, while they give the static pressure and temperature at the exit.

What is the reason for this? Is it just convenience because you usually have the total values more readily available in practice? Or is there a deeper physical meaning behind the use of total pressure at the inlet?